# Cocos2D with new RevMobAds framework

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, revmob

Integrated new RevMob.frmework in Cocos2D games.

Now getting many compilation error in my Cocos2D 1.0 game and only linker error in other cocos2D 2.0 game.

In Cocos2D 2.0, Linker errors are:

```
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
```

Which system framework missed? Already added StoreKit.framework

In cocos2D 1.0, along with these linker error, getting some compilation errors too.
 It is showing "Expected a property attribute before *, in below line(in RevMobAds.framewors)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

How can I over come all these problem and get new revMob sdk in cocos2d game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This errors happen due to the use of LLVM GCC 4.2 as a compiler, to solve this issues just make the following changes:

RevMobBanner.h
line 35: change "strong" to "retain"

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

RevMobButton.h
line 51: erase "atomic"

```
@property (readonly) RevMobButtonStatus status;
```

RevMobFullscreen.h
line 25:  change "strong" to "retain"

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

Comment: thanks. Now no compilation error. Any idea how to solve above linker error? Already added storeKit, also it says ld: RevMobAds.framework/RevMobAds, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice for architecture armv6, my game supports iOS 3 too...Is it possible to use new revMob with my code?

Comment: The StoreKit need to be with optional library, just like the Paulo's screenshot.

Comment: Regarding to armv6, the support to this architecture was dropped to support the armv7s (iPhone 5). To support iOS 6 it's necessary to use Xcode 4.5 that don't support armv6, so you need to choose armv6 or iOS 6. The market share of iOS 6 is 10 times bigger than armv6 (iPhone, iPhone 3G, iPod Touch 1st and 2nd generations).

Comment: They release a new version of the SDK, looks like it don't have this link errors in old Xcode versions (4.4 an earlier)

Answer (score 1):

Linker error:

Make sure RevMob.framework is added to the target's "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase.

Compiler error:

Looks fine to me. Make sure #import  is imported in that file. Better yet, add it to the prefix.pch if it's not there.

If you continue having issues I suggest getting support directly from RevMob.

Comment: already added framework in Link Binary with Libraries..still same linker error.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the RevMob and StoreKit Frameworks added in the Build Phases: http://sdk.revmob.com/ios

Also, trying to upgrade your XCode, because this is related to a incompatibility issue with old versions of iOS.

Or wait for a new version of the SDK that may have this incompatibility issue fixed.

[image: Screenshot XCode Build Phases]

Comment: already added all these framework. Not updated my xcode..ok I can update and try.